# In Vue Router, how do you know if you can't go back

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to write a method that links to the homepage if I can't go back.

a code a bit like that:

```
      if (**router.back.length == 0**){
         router.push({name:"Home"})
       }else {
         router.back();
       }
    }
```

the problem is i dont know how to tell if the .back () is possible or not.

I am currently on a pageNotFound, I go to the current page using the following redirect

```
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
    name: "PageNotFound",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "NotFound" */ "@/views/PageNotFound.vue")
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking in the Vue Router doc I found the solution

```
goBack() {
      if(this.$router.getRoutes().length==0){
        this.$router.push({name:"Home"})
      }else{
        this.$router.back();
      }
    }
```

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-onready

Answer (score 0):

Had similar case once. Try something like this (treat it like a pseudo code):

```
  data: () => ({
     fromRoute: null
  }),
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.fromRoute = from;
    })
  },
  methods: () {
    handleBack() {
      if (!this.fromRoute.name) {
        router.push({name:"Home"});
      } else {
        router.back();
      }
    }
  }
```

More info here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-go-back-or-go-home/30242/3

Comment: unfortunately the "if" condition is always validated, I never enter the "else". I have console.log(this.fromRoute.name) and this fromRoute is always "undifined".

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to achieve the desired result. Make sure you are using `[Named Routes][1]`.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fromRoute: null
    };
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      vm.fromRoute = from;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    goBack() {
      if (!this.fromRoute.name) {
        this.$router.push("/");
      } else {
        this.$router.back();
      }
    },
  },
};


  [1]: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html
```